# Read only textbox @Html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

Here i tried to add ReadOnly textbox,but its not working.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m.ProjectManagement,htmlAttributes: new {style="width:100%",@readonly="readonly" })
```

Comment: I can tell you that this statement may give you a compilation/run error.

Comment: if the answer helps you to your goal, mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m.ProjectManagement, new {style="width:100%",@readonly="readonly" })
```

try this

This is the official documentation for TextBOxFor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.108).aspx

I cannot provide you a jsfiddle, but this works, I've tested it in a local project on my computer.

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

> Parameters htmlHelper Type: System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper The HTML
>   helper instance that this method extends.
>    expression Type:
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> An
>   expression that identifies the object that contains the properties to
>   render.
>   htmlAttributes Type: System.Object An object that contains the
>   HTML attributes to set for the element.

Answer (score 1):

then try this:

```
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectManagement, new {style="width:100%",@readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```